# DataRetrieving: get amount of empty nodes of firebase and Dart

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dart, flutter

this is my code:

```
int routineCount =0;
var response2 = await FirebaseDatabase.instance
    .reference()
    .child("Users")
    .child(userId)
    .child("currentRoutine")
    .once();
response2.value.forEach((k)=>routineCount++);
```

In this case I have one child node of "currentRoutine" but I want to keep track of the total amount of direct children of "currentRoutine"
for example "2" if it would exist.

and this is my Json Firebase(Couldn't  copy it the right way as text):

[image]

Comment: This does not look like valid firebase data. Where did you copy it from exactly?

Comment: @AndréKool I exported it with the export button from firebase